# (Py-) CUDA under Linux from live USB stick

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, usb, cuda

My question is similar to [this previous question from 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14498754/cuda-opencl-on-ubuntu-that-is-installed-on-a-usb-drive).

What I would like to have is a USB stick with a Linux installation on it such that I can boot from the stick and run PyCUDA programs on the GPU. That is, I need a live Linux stick with CUDA installation.

Is that possible? Has anybody done it? Can it be done such that the CUDA installation remains and keeps working when plugging the stick into another computer?

Comment: In a purely live session no, but you can install the full Ubuntu the same way you would in an internal drive *and* install all the required drivers. In summary, it's a false problem.

Comment: @MichaelBay Thanks for the hint, I will read more into that. What do you mean by "false problem"?

Comment: It's a false problem because it doesn't matter where Ubuntu is installed.

Comment: @MichaelBay Ok, seems that this answers my question indeed, thanks again.

Comment: For the Live session to remain in RAM when the USB stick is removed, usually you put a `toram` option on the kernel line that loads so that it loads the entire OS into RAM instead.